# Cocos2d-x: CCmoveto move to opposite position

Tags: cocos2d-x

I have a lot of sprites. Then i use CCtouchMoved to move that sprites to a position ccp(0,0);

But when i run, theare are some sprite move to correct position, and some are move to the opposite of the position a want it to move to.Here is my function

```
void sample::moveto(CCSprite* sprite, CCPoint pointToMove){

    CCFiniteTimeAction* moveTo = CCMoveTo::create(0.5f, pointToMove);
    CCFiniteTimeAction* scale = CCScaleTo::create(0.5f, 0.0f); 
    sprite->runAction(scale);
    CCFiniteTimeAction* finishMove = CCCallFuncN::create(this,
        callfuncN_selector(NoteScene::swallowUpKeywordFinish));
    sprite->runAction(CCSequence::create(moveTo,finishMove,NULL));
}
```

Any help will be appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sprite->stopAllActions();` before starting new actions.